# How to combine n-grams into one vocabulary in Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, nlp, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

Wondering if there is a built-in Spark feature to combine 1-, 2-, n-gram features into a single vocabulary. Setting `n=2` in `NGram` followed by invocation of `CountVectorizer` results in a dictionary containing only 2-grams. What I really want is to combine all frequent 1-grams, 2-grams, etc into one dictionary for my corpus.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can train separate `NGram` and `CountVectorizer` models and merge using `VectorAssembler`.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import NGram, CountVectorizer, VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline


def build_ngrams(inputCol="tokens", n=3):

    ngrams = [
        NGram(n=i, inputCol="tokens", outputCol="{0}_grams".format(i))
        for i in range(1, n + 1)
    ]

    vectorizers = [
        CountVectorizer(inputCol="{0}_grams".format(i),
            outputCol="{0}_counts".format(i))
        for i in range(1, n + 1)
    ]

    assembler = [VectorAssembler(
        inputCols=["{0}_counts".format(i) for i in range(1, n + 1)],
        outputCol="features"
    )]

    return Pipeline(stages=ngrams + vectorizers + assembler)
```

Example usage:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  (1, ["a", "b", "c", "d"]),
  (2, ["d", "e", "d"])
], ("id", "tokens"))

build_ngrams().fit(df).transform(df)
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: An alternative would be to combine the unigrams and bigrams using `VectorAssembler` then feed a single vector to `CountVectorizer`. I think this is more in line with scikit-learn CountVectorizer. Not sure if it makes a real difference though.

Comment: @danieln If nothing changed `VectorAssembler` cannot assemble arrays of strings.

Comment: How would you go about feeding n-gram range, like (1,3) to HashigTF?