# Ngrams works in Hive but not in spark-shell (Scala)

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hive, user-defined-functions

I really stuck in my issue and I searched extensively in the Net, but I couldn't find a solution for that, and I'm new to Spark-shell (Scala). `ngrams` function works in Hive perfectly fine by the below command:

```
select ngrams(split(name, '\\W+'), 2, 3) from mytable
```

which returns top 3 bigram of column "name". When I call it in spark-shell by this command

```
val df = hiveContext.sql("select ngrams(split(name, '\\W+'), 2, 3) from mytable")
```

I got these errors:

**Spark 2**

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'ngrams'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.
```

**Spark 1.6**

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No handler for udf class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDAFnGrams
```

I also tried these ways with no success:

1. I separated `split` from `ngrams`, i. e. I ran `split` first, then ran `ngrams`. Surprisingly, `split` works fine but `ngrams` does not.
2. I tried `sqlContext.register.udf("ngrams", ngrams)` and received: `error: not found: value ngrams`
3. I added 2 different Jar files versions (`hive-exec-1.2.0.jar` and `hive-exec-3.0.0.jar`) using this command:

   `spark-shell --jars /hive-exec-1.2.0.jar`

   `spark-shell --jars /hive-exec-3.0.0.jar`

and same errors.

I found the open source for `ngrams` function in this [github](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDAFnGrams.java), but it is in Java and I dont know if I could call it in Spark-shell (Scala).

Maybe this is a trivial issue, and I would really appreciate it if someone could help me.

> I'm using Scala 2.11.8, Java 1.8, Spark 2.3.0 and Spark 1.6

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#n-gram. About the error - are you sure you've enabled Hive support?

Comment: so how should I do that?

Comment: If you create `SparkSession` (Spark 2.x) `val spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()`

Comment: Using Spark 2, I got this:  error: value builder is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

Comment: you would want to use https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/ml-features.html#n-gram

Comment: @hadooper thank you. How can I get , say, top 3 of 1-gram or 2-gram using that Scala function? Also how can I apply it to a column, i. e. input>column, output>coulmn, like ngram function that Hive does?

Comment: @user8371915 I created SparkSession.builder like the one you mentioned, but no success, or I might run the wrong command. if you run it on your system, please let me know. Also you posted a code for ngram here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48461076/how-do-i-create-a-set-of-ngrams-in-spark this code would extremely help me if something changed. First I think your code does not handle a case where we have only one word in a string but looking for , say, 3-gram. Second, I don't know how to apply it to my table to receive all sets of ngrams for one specific column.